# Find highest sold item name for each date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables

```
table 1: items (int,itemName)
table 2: orders(order id,oDate)
table 3: orderDetails(orderId, itemId, itemQnt)
```

Here is the [complete schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fe97) with some demo values

What is the best way to find top sold `itemName` for each day.
Output would be like `date,itemName`.

Comment: Top sold in $ or just basic quantity? What if there are ties? And do you need to fill in gaps, e.g. if nothing was sold yesterday should there be a row? And finally, what version of SQL Server are you using? 2000? 2014? Something in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want ties:

```
;WITH od AS
(
  SELECT o.oDate, od.itemId, 
    r = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY o.oDate ORDER BY SUM(od.itemQnt) DESC)
  FROM dbo.orderDetails AS od
  INNER JOIN dbo.orders AS o
  ON od.orderId = o.orderId
  GROUP BY o.oDate, od.itemId
)
SELECT od.oDate, i.name, r, rn
FROM od INNER JOIN dbo.items AS i
ON od.itemId = i.itemId
WHERE r = 1
ORDER BY od.oDate;
```

If you don't want ties, change `RANK()` to `ROW_NUMBER()`, just note that it will pick an arbitrary winner unless you add some kind of tie-breaker to the `ORDER BY`.

If you need to fill in gaps in some date range, for example if yesterday had no sales but you still want a row, you can generate a set of dates first, and then use an outer join (this example returns rows from January 1 -> January 15 inclusive):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE, @endDate DATE;
SELECT @startDate = '20150101',
       @endDate   = '20150115';

;WITH [days](d) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)+1)
    DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (ORDER BY [object_id])-1, @startDate)
  FROM sys.all_columns
  ORDER BY [object_id]
),
od AS
(
  SELECT o.oDate, od.itemId, 
    r = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY o.oDate ORDER BY SUM(od.itemQnt) DESC)
  FROM dbo.orderDetails AS od
  INNER JOIN dbo.orders AS o
  ON od.orderId = o.orderId
  GROUP BY o.oDate, od.itemId
)
SELECT oDate = d.d, 
  name = COALESCE(i.name, '<n/a>')
FROM [days] AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN od
ON d.d = od.oDate
AND od.r = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.items AS i
ON od.itemId = i.itemId
ORDER BY d.d;
```

(Also, do you really think it's productive to make slightly shorter but far more obscure and difficult-to-remember column names like `oDate` and `itemQnt`? And why isn't there a unique constraint on `orderDetails(orderId, itemId)`? Finally, please [stay away from regional, ambiguous formats like `mm/dd/yyyy`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).)

Answer (score 2):

You get the highest quantity using a `RANK`. This might return multiple rows with the highest rank, if you don't want that you might switch to a `ROW_NUMBER` instead [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e38e4/1):

```
select *
from
 (
   select o.oDate, od.itemId, 
      sum(itemQnt) as Qnt,
      rank()
      over (partition by o.oDate
            order by sum(itemQnt) desc) as rnk
   from orders as o join orderDetails as od
   on o.orderId = od.orderId
   group by o.oDate, od.itemId
) as dt 
where rnk = 1
```

Simply join that result to your `items` table